# snp.svg Triggering a click event

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

Just can't figure out how to do i.

I have a click event:

```
elem.click(function (){
  // do stuff ...
}
```

now how to call this event with a function?

`elem` has this click event in `elem.events['2'].f` but when I call it I get back `undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

ok, so it was as easy as:

```
allPaths[35].events[2].f.call(allPaths[35]);
```